# How to automate testing of audio quality across a network?

Tags: c++, automation, packet-capture

I am working with a team developing a C++ application for making audio calls.

I am new to the team and will be involved in testing the app. I have experience with C++ but have no idea how one would test the audio quality of the application.

Are there any C++ classes I could use to automate quality testing, or external apps that could be integrated with Jenkins?

Comment: One non qualitative way would be to do a binary comparison of the source and destination audio. It would give you a rough idea.